# Unity Intersection of two game objects without changing the position

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there any possibility to see if two GameObjects would intersect if I change the position of one of them ?
Context: I have a cube GameObject and a wall. I want to update the position of the cube only if I know that the new position would not lead to an intersection of the cube and the wall. Is that possible ?

Comment: Note sure why you’re downvoted. But you can use Physics.BoxCast to determine if there will be a collision ahead of time.